# Keycloak Unknown authentication mechanism

Tags: wildfly-8, errai, keycloak

I need help with using keycloak in an Errai app. I am getting an error about "unknown authentication method" for "KEYCLOAK" ? I have the keycloak-appliance running (on a different port though), and the Errai app has a  with KEYCLOAK in the web.xml file inside WEB-INF
When I run the Errai app with mvn gwt:run, I get  : RuntimeException caused by "Unknown authentication mechanism KEYCLOAK". I have no idea how to go around this issue .

Comment: Btw, if you are only starting to implement your application consider using Spring Security adapter - you will be able to create `war` file which will work both on JBoss and Tomcat for example, without installing extra adapter to server.

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to add a little more detail to @cfsnyder's answer.  In order for your application server to recognize a definition in the web.xml that looks like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>internal</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

you'll need to tell jboss (in this instance) how to interpret that particular auth method.  At the time of my answer, this is in [section 8.2 of the Keycloak docs](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/ch08.html#jboss-adapter).

First, [download the keycloak adapter](http://keycloak.jboss.org/keycloak/downloads.html?dir=0%3Dadapters/keycloak-oidc%3B) (remember, this is *not* the same as the Keycloak Server).  Next, unzip the download in the wildfly home directory.  With your application server running, just use the following command to install the Keycloak configuration into the appropriate files:

```
jboss-cli.sh -c --file=adapter-install.cli
```

When this script completes, your configuration file will have the new entry added to accommodate the `KEYCLOAK` entry in your web.xml.  The script will add something like this to either a domain.xml or standalone.xml:

```
            <security-domain name="keycloak">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

Once you have the Keycloak module files provided by the adapter + the security domain configuration to link the `KEYCLOAK` method to the appropriate `LoginModule`, you should be all set.

Comment: The download link just redirects to the site's main page.

Comment: one final step -- after running cli - do restart the wildfly :)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to install and configure the Wildfly adapter in order for your Errai app to recognize the "KEYCLOAK" authentication method. See section 7.2 of the [Keycloak documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.0.4.Final/userguide/pdf/keycloak-reference-guide-en-US.pdf).

Comment: @freedev thanks for pointing that out. cfsnyder could you please modify?

Answer (score 0):

To add to @josh-cain's answer, you might also need following additions in your domain.xml or standalone.xml:

To `<extensions></extensions>`, add:

```
   <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-subsystem"/>
```

To `<profile></profile>`, add:

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1"/>
```

The adapter installation cli scripts can fail for various reasons so you might need to add these entries manually.